# PHP handling multi-dimensional object//array from AJAX Jquery post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a large multi-dimensional object of arrays in JS that I am trying to pass to PHP using Ajax. The keys of some of the array values are written arrays `test[key]`, and in PHP I want them to be read as such `test => array([key] => 123)`. Note, I am working in Wordpress.

**Working example**

JS:

```
var args = {
    'action' : 'save',
    'test[key1]' : ['123', 'abc']
}

var request = $.ajax({
    url: settings.get('ajaxurl'),
    data: args,
    type: 'post',
    success: function(response) { // }
});
```

PHP print_r on output:

```
[action] => save
[test] => Array
    (
        [key1] => Array
             (
                 [0] => 123
                 [1] => 234
             )
      )
```

However, I want to send all of the `test[key1]` (and a lot more data) at the second level of the object. I have a lot of data and need them grouped accordingly.

**Not working example**

JS:

```
// simple changing the args
var args = {
    'action' : 'save',
    'data' : {  
        'test[key1]' : ['123', 'abc']
    }
}
```

PHP print_r on output:

```
[action] => save  
[data] => Array
    (
        [test[key1] => Array
             (
                 [0] => 123
                 [1] => 234
             )
     )
```

This seems to be really difficult to explain - but it looks like PHP isn't parsing the array keys properly when it's not on the top level of the array.  Am I doing something wrong // is there a way around this?  I can provide more insight if needed, I attempted to make this as clear as possible.

When printing the keys of the data array, it prints them without the final `]`.  So it shows `test[key1` instead of what I am expecting.  Maybe they get stripped somewhere?

Comment: PHP is doing it right, maybe you are the one thats a little confused

Comment: @RiggsFolly I edited my title - I wasn't intending on blaming PHP, I definitely think I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: In `args` you are attempting to create 2 properties with the same name `test[key1]` thats not legal in any language, Is it?

Comment: @RiggsFolly well it'd just overwrite it... but you are right - in attempting to simplify my code I did make that mistake.  I edited it to reflect what I am actually doing..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to stringify the data

```
var request = $.ajax({
   url: settings.get('ajaxurl'),
   data: JSON.stringify(args),
   type: 'post',
   success: function(response) { // }});
```

Then use [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to make it useful in PHP.

**Edit:**

This might get you where you want to go...

```
var args = {
'action' : 'save',
test : {
   key1 : [
    '123',
    'abc' ]
  } }
```

Since JavaScript does not allow for associative arrays.

Comment: jQuery should do all that for you

Comment: I attempted this - but I couldn't get the stringify and action that WP uses to behave properly (Probably a different issue, but I wanted to figure out what I was doing wrong here first).

Comment: So I ended up getting this to work - in the sense that the slashes weren't stripped, but after parsing the JSON back in PHP, it didn't read the array as I wanted and just depicted the key as a string.  `test[key1]` instead of as an array

Answer (score 0):

Please try this args, this will give multi-dimensional array result.

```
    var args = {
    'action' : 'save',
    'data' : {  
        'test': {
            'key1' : ['123', 'abc']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not manually creating this object - so it would require looping through each key and breaking it apart as such.  I'm not entirely sure how to do this (maybe regex) - as I am not sure what the key pairs will be.

Comment: you have to create an object same as args. if you could send me the complete code then will help you.

Comment: I am grabbing the keys from the `name` on `input` attributes.  perhaps thats enough to work from? `var key = $('input').attr('name');`